# Alternative for Tomcat web sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, safari, websocket

I am using `TOMCAT WEBSOCKETS` and is working fine in all browsers except in Safari where it is throwing 426 error and that is because websocket client is not conforming to the WebSocket standard RFC-6455.
Safari 5.x isn't using the final WebSocket spec, but rather an early experimental draft version, something that tomcat does not correctly support.
I am thinking of using other web socket which is stable and supports all browsers.
I need some help in selecting web socket written in JAVA

Comment: The only other option that I am familiar with is Jetty, I haven't tested with Safari but you could give it a shot.

Comment: What exact version of Tomcat are you using? If Safari 5.x doesn't support the spec, I think you probably simply can't use Safari 5.x. If you use something written in Java, you'll need an applet, a plug-in, permissions, etc. Better to just require that your users use a standards-compliant browser.